# Difference between response.status() vs. response.sendStatus() in express

Tags: node.js, express

What is the difference between `response.status()` and  `response.sendStatus()` in Express.

I notice that one is used generally for post, get, and other middleware, while the later is used in delete requests. Why is this?

Answer (score 41):

`status()` sets a HTTP status on the response (as a Javascript object on the server side).

`sendStatus()` sets the status *and* sends it to the client.

The usage doesn't depend on the HTTP method of the request. In most cases you would use `sendStatus` anyway since it's unlikely that the status changes once the request is processed (especially since status code is the first line in a raw HTTP response).

Read more in the docs:

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus

Answer (score 31):

`res.sendStatus` is shorthand for implementing `res.send` and `res.status`

the link shared by @freakish explains it all.

```
res.sendStatus(200); // equivalent to res.status(200).send('OK')
res.sendStatus(403); // equivalent to res.status(403).send('Forbidden')
res.sendStatus(404); // equivalent to res.status(404).send('Not Found')
res.sendStatus(500); // equivalent to res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')
```

Comment: Maybe it's equivalent is instead `res.status(statusCode).end()`

Answer (score 11):

As *freakish* already pointed out, `sendStatus` sets and sends the status.

This means that if you want to both set a status and send a body you have to use `status`. For example, you want to set an error status, and send a body with a JSON that explains why the error occured, you first have to set the status (using `status`), and then send the JSON (using `send`). If you had already set the status with `sendStatus`, it is no longer possible to send the JSON, because you already used a form of sent.

Comment: Spent some time to figure out why im getting this error "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". I was chaining json method with sendStatus.

Answer (score 2):

`sendStatus(code)` is a function that *duplicates* the standard status message corresponding to the provided status code *into the body*:

```js
app.get('/a', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(500)
})
```

```http
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error     <--- this status message (aka "reason phrase")
<response headers>

Internal Server Error                  <--- gets duplicated here in body
```

[See here for its implementation](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.18.1/lib/response.js#L369). There is no obvious need to do that, because the status message (the text after "`500` ") will be there regardless. The above is NOT a normal HTTP idiom. Who knows why it was added into the express response. Moreover, when you send a non-empty body along with a status to a browser, it will render that body rather than a standard stylish page:

[image: Internal Server Error]

---

`res.status(500).send()` is sufficient to respond in a standard way:

```js
app.get('/b', (req, res) => {
    res.status(500).send()
})
```

```http
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error     <--- status message
<response headers>
                                       <--- empty body
```

[image: This page isn't working. 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500]

This is what everyone expects if there is nothing to say beyond status code & message.

Answer (score 0):

no it's not for special routers like delete
The diffrence is `res.status()` only sets header and when you send response (`res.send()`) it will send to user
but `res.sendStatus()` sends the response at the moment without response body