# Unhandled promise error in Node and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I was making CRUD APIs with NodeJS, ExpressJS, and Mongoose, on executing the following code I got an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error for line number 29. Despite having a try-catch block.

Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
require('../src/db/conn.js');
const MensRanking = require('../src/models/mens.js');
app.use(express.json());
app.get('/', async (req, res) =>{
    res.send("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
})

app.post('/mens', async (req, res) =>{
    try{
        const addingMensRecords = new MensRanking(req.body);
        console.log(req.body);
        const insert = await addingMensRecords.save();
        res.sendStatus(201).send(insert);
    }
    catch(e){
        res.sendStatus(400).send(e);
    }
})  

app.get('/mens', async (req, res) =>{
    try{
        const getMens = await MensRanking.find({});
        res.sendStatus(201).send(getMens);
    }
    catch(e){
        res.sendStatus(400).send(e);
    }
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`\nlistening at http://127.0.0.1:${port}\n`);
})
```

Error:

```
(node:20016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\projects\rest-api-sections\rest-tute\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (D:\projects\rest-api-sections\rest-tute\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:599:15)
    at ServerResponse.sendStatus (D:\projects\rest-api-sections\rest-tute\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:357:8)
    at D:\projects\rest-api-sections\rest-tute\src\app.js:29:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:20016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20016) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

[Here is the complete code repository](https://github.com/Samar-080301/rest-api)

Comment: The error message "*Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client*" seems self-descriptive. You're trying to set the headers but you've already sent the response to che client.

Comment: "One, two, three, four, five..." Seriously, people aren't going to count to 29 to help you. Tell us what line is line 29! :-)

Comment: try `res.status` or `res.setStatus` instead of `sendStatus`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620682/difference-between-response-status-vs-response-sendstatus-in-express/38621009

Comment: *"Despite having a try-catch block."* Probably the error is being thrown by code in the `catch` block. That would reject the promise for the `async` function it's in, which isn't handled by anything in that code. Remember: Code in `catch` blocks is code. This is one of the reasons **not** to pass an `async` function callback to something (Express, in this case) that isn't going to handle the promise.

Comment: @SamarPratapSingh added an answer with the solution and the link that Robert posted as a reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `res.status` instead of `sendStatus`

[Difference between response.status() vs. response.sendStatus() in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620682/difference-between-response-status-vs-response-sendstatus-in-express/38621009)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
require('../src/db/conn.js');
const MensRanking = require('../src/models/mens.js');
app.use(express.json());
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');
});

app.post('/mens', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const addingMensRecords = new MensRanking(req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    const insert = await addingMensRecords.save();
    res.status(201).send(insert);
  }
  catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});

app.get('/mens', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const getMens = await MensRanking.find({});
    res.status(201).send(getMens);
  }
  catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`\nlistening at http://127.0.0.1:${port}\n`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `sendStatus` function of epxress.js as it immediately sends that particular assigned code to the response object which triggers response before your data is set, so when your `send` function is called response object has already been sent, hence the error:

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Instead, use this when you need to set HTTP Response codes as well alongside data

```
res.status(RESPONSE_CODE).send(DATA)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problematic function in this case i just highlight one, because they have the same errors:

```
app.post('/mens', async (req, res) =>{
try{
    const addingMensRecords = new MensRanking(req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    const insert = await addingMensRecords.save();
    res.sendStatus(201).send(insert);
}
catch(e){
    res.sendStatus(400).send(e);
}})
```

1. You already sent a response in your try-block with res.sendStatus(201) and trying to send again with .send(insert) -> throws exception
2. After that you do the same error again with res.sendStatus(400).send(e);

The following code should do what you tried to intend:

```
app.post('/mens', async (req, res) =>{
try{
    const addingMensRecords = new MensRanking(req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    const insert = await addingMensRecords.save();
    res.status(201).send(insert);
}
catch(e){
    res.status(400).send(e);
}})
```