# Failed to POST: Post "http://localhost:3000/webhook": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have this error when I run `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/webhook` on cmd and server on hyperterminal.
[stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/webhook][1]

I basically copied and pasted from the document so I'm not sure what is the problem
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iosZa.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk0xY.png

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY);
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  const payload = request.body;

  console.log("Got payload: " + payload);

  response.status(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `response.status(200)` does not actually *send* the response. For that you need to use `sendStatus(200)` ([docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus)) or follow your `status(200)` with a `send()` (see [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status)).

Also this previous answer, related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38621009/12474862